# pass if code in django, if something in data -> pass

Tags: django, python-3.x

my code is take reques.body and into data var. 
and if data dic in username or email or telephone then checking password.
and if password collect i return token.
but my code is just pass all if.
i think if  @ in dic it is can check key in dic

i used httpie and send password and telephone or email or username.
but all pass.

i dont know what i mistake.
plz help me!

```
class UserLoginView(View):
def post(self, request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    check_password = int(data['password'])
    check_username = 'username'

    if check_username in data:
        login_username = data['username']
        login_user = User.objects.filter(username=login_username)
        if login_user is None:
            return JsonResponse({'message':'have not this ussername User'}, status = 400)
        elif login_user is login_username:
            get_user = User.objects.get(username=login_username)
            if check_password is not get_user.password:
                return JsonResponse({'message':'Not collect password'}, status = 400)
            else:
                encoded_token = jwt.encode({'user': login_user}, 'wecode', algorithm='HS256')
                return JsonResponse({'token':encoded_token}, status = 200)

    elif 'email' in data:
        login_email = data['email']
        login_user = User.objects.filter(email=login_email)
        if login_user is None:
            return JsonResponse({'message':'have not this emain User'}, status = 400)
        elif login_user is login_email:
            get_user = User.objects.get(email=login_email)
            if check_password is not get_user.password:
                return JsonResponse({'message':'Not collect password'}, status = 400)
            else:
                encoded_token = jwt.encode({'user': login_user}, 'wecode', algorithm='HS256')
                return JsonResponse({'token':encoded_token}, status = 200)

    elif 'telephone' in data:
        login_telephone = data['telephone']
        login_user = User.objects.filter(telephone=login_telephone)
        if login_user is None:
            return JsonResponse({'message':'have not this telephone User'}, status = 400)
        elif login_user is login_telephone:
            get_user = User.objects.get(telephone=login_telephone)
            if check_password is not get_user.password:
                return JsonResponse({'message':'Not collect password'}, status = 400)
            else:
                encoded_token = jwt.encode({'user': login_user}, 'wecode', algorithm='HS256')
                return JsonResponse({'token':encoded_token}, status = 200)

    return JsonResponse({'message':'Nothing do'}, status = 200)
```

Comment: Do you mean it directly return JSONResponse?

Comment: @ Biplove Lamichhane i wanna return token.. this code for login, so need check user info. . i try make API like Instargram

Comment: Is your goal just to check if the user is logged in?